# How to separate line in tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, line-breaks

```py
tuples = [
          ('Vehicle MOB','2021','Nov'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2021','Dec'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022','Jan'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022','Feb'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022','Mar'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022','Apr'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022','May'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022','Jun'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022','Jul'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022','Aug'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022','Sep'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022','Oct'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022','Nov'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022','Dec'),
         ('Vehicle MOB','2022MY\ntotal','')]
Final=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2], columns=Final)
```

I want to break line

```
2022MY
TOTAL
```

How can i do it ?

[image]

Comment: That's not "broken", that's a separate row.  You want `('Vehicle MOB','2022MY','total')]`.

Answer (score 1):

The line break that you added is already exported to the Excel file that you seem to want to generate. All you have to do is enable text wrapping for that cell.

[image]